# Empty elements in JS array declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, declaration

it's my first question here, after have been reading for years, so be nice with me please.

I'm having trouble with array management in js/jq.

I have array with several elements, which is processed with $.each function.
I want to extract matching elements to another array and return this array.
But for some reason (don't know if it's because array declaration, jquery.each function...) I'm having first empty element.

I think I'm making this more difficult to understand than it's, so made jsfiddle.

```
var arr = new Array();
$.each([1,2,3], function(index,element){
    if (element == 2){
        arr[index] = element;
    }
});
```

arr must have only 1 element, but arr.length returns 2 because first array slot is empty.

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/moay7y95/

I'm so sure that it's a simple and little stupid thing, but I've not been able to find an answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've been thinking about if use array is the best way to do that.

Finally, I'm going to use objects, declaring arr like arr={}.

With objects, I can have index like [1,4,5,6 ] with no problem.

Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Best solution: Use `.filter`**

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3].filter(function(value){
    return value == 2
});
```

If the return value is true, the element is included in the returned array, otherwise it is ignored. This is pure js, so you don't need jquery. See documentation about [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

**Your problem: Use `.push`**

Try using the `.push` method on the array (see [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)).

```
var arr = new Array();
$.each([1,2,3], function(index,element){
    if (element == 2){
        arr.push(element);
    }
});
```

The `.push` method will dynamically grow your array as elements are added.

Your problem is that the value of `index` inside your function is a reference point in your initial array. This means that if you look at the returned array, you will find `[undefined, 2]` and so the length is returning as 2. If your condition were `element == 3` you would have two empty slots.

**Alternatively: Use `.grep`**

Another jQuery method is `$.grep`. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/

```
var arr = $.grep([1, 2, 3], function (value) {
    return value == 2
});
```

This is jQuery's implementation of javascript's `.filter`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know that stackoverflow works very good, but not so much!
I was confused about arrays and json objects (which I'm using), didn't think about array indexes start on 0.

Now it's all clear.

Answer (score 4):

You are pushing an element in array at `1`st index. So, javascript by default put `undefined` at `0`th index.

So, at the end of `each` your array will be

```
[undefined, 2];
```

This is the reason you get the `length` as 2.

You can use `push` to add element in array:

```
$.each([1, 2, 3], function (index, element) {
    if (element == 2) {
        arr.push(element);
        elem++;
    }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/moay7y95/2/

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 2):

Your array `[1, 2, 3]` has three elements, and three associated indexes: 0, 1 and 2. In each iteration of your `$.each()` loop over that array, the index and its value get passed to the function.

So the first call gets `0, 1` passed as its arguments. The second call gets `1, 2` passed as its arguments, then the `if` statement condition evaluates to true, so your code:

```
arr[index] = element;
```

is actually equivalent to

```
arr[1] = 2;
```

Since you're inserting an element at index 1, you'll end up with an empty index 0.

You could instead simply use [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add the element to the array:

```
arr.push(element);
```

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned the problem is you are assigning the value at index 1, so the array will be considered of length 2.

One solution is to use .push() instead of assigning based on index.

Another approach could be is to use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and return true if the element matches the conditon

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3].filter(function(value){
    return value == 2
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/82zjkuak/)

---

Using [$.grep()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/)

```
var arr = $.grep([1, 2, 3], function (value) {
    return value == 2
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[1, 2, 3]

if (element == 2)

arr[index] = element;
```

This means you're **setting arr[1]** to element.

If you want to add it to the arr sequentially (filling it up normally), **push it** into art

`arr.push(element);`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're looking for [Array.filter (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
var elems = ["car", "bike"];
var arr = [1, 2, 3, "car", 5, "bike"].filter(myFilterFunc);

function myFilterFunc(val) {
    if (elems.indexOf(val) > -1) return true;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/moay7y95/3/)**